# DirectX 11 objects stretch the closer they are to the edge of the window

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine, directx-11

This is link to a [video](https://youtu.be/x7qW8JHvpLk).
There was a simple cube with a rotating camera, and i found this problem.

So i created matrices using glm (also tried directx math), for aspect ratio i used window 1920 x 1080 and his resolution without titlebar. I tested this scene on game engines like UE and Unity but everything was fine there.I don’t know what to do, are there any solutions?

There is View And Projection Matrices (FMatrix4 is typedef for glm::mat4x4):

```
FMatrix4 Camera::GetViewMatrix()
{
    CameraForward = Orientation;
    return glm::lookAt(CameraPosition, CameraPosition + CameraForward, CameraUp);
    //CameraPosition = FVector(-3, 0, -2);
    //return glm::lookAt(CameraPosition, FVector(0.1f,0.01f, 0.1f), CameraUp);
}

FMatrix4 Camera::GetPerspectiveMatrix()
{
    //WinProc->GetAspectRatio()
    return glm::perspective(glm::radians(CameraFOV), WinProc->GetAspectRatio(), 0.1f, 100.0f);
}
```

Camera FOV 90 degrees

Comment: This looks like an artifact of setting your field of view too high. Edit your question to show how you constructed your projection matrix.

Comment: yep, just normal perspective effects

Comment: @Botje Already edited.